# Java / Android ArrayList in different Activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to get an Arraylist to work in another Activity on Android. All is well. The arrray list is created, however, I cannot get Intent to work.

What way is there to get an arraylist to another variable?

Here is the code I'm using to generate the arrayList:

```
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
List<Contact> ContactpList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
```

How will I go about making this arraylist available in my other activities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your activity were you have array list Right:

```
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
List<Contact> ContactpList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
```

now when u call another activity then send the array object like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(youractivity.this,youractivity.class);
intent.putExtra("ContactpList ", ContactpList );
startActivity(intent);
```

now get this array in the activity which you have called and were u want to get the array:

```
ArrayList<String> resultArray = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("ContactpList ");
```

Hope it is work for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("list");
```

or other way that to make `static` your arraylist and access via class name.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `ArrayList<Contact> list` and pass it to another activity via `bundle` like this:

passing:  `<your intent>.putExtra("List", list);`

getting:  `getIntent().getSerializableExtra("List");`

make sure `Contact class` is `Serializable` : add `public Class Contact implements Serializable {}`

OR you can make a `Static` variable :

```
public static ArrayList<Contact> list = new ArrayList<Contact>();
```